# Testing Presence: true validation in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, unit-testing

In my holder test file:

```
 test "name must be present" do
  holder = Holder.new(name: "name")
  assert holder.valid?
 end

 test "name must not be blank" do
  h = Holder.new(name: "    ")
  assert !h.valid?
 end

 test "name must not be nil" do
  h = Holder.new(name: nil)
  assert !h.valid?
 end
```

And my holder model looks like:

```
class Holder < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :description, :name, :user_id

  validates_length_of :name, maximum: 75
  validates_length_of :description, maximum: 250

  validate :name, presence: true
end
```

But, when I run my tests the last two validations are still red. What do I need to do to test them so they turn green?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot `s` in your `validate`. It has to be:

```
validates :name, presence: true
```

`validate` and `validates` are completely different methods.

See there: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Validations/ClassMethods.html.

Comment: Thanks so much! I should have asked earlier, I've been pulling my hair out over this!